# Query daterange with separate date and time fields - SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to display table AFRU in Crystal Reports filtered by date and time.
For example: 01.07.2019 05:00 to 03.07.2019 12:00.

That means:

- On 01.07.2019 I want all data from 05:00 in the morning
- On 02.07.2019 I want the whole day
- On 03.07.2019 I want the data till 12:00

The problem is that the date and time field are separated in sap (AFRU.IEDD and AFRU.IEDZ).
If I enter 05:00 to 12:00 it's used on every day.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a formula field: `DateTime({AFRU.IEDD} & " " & {AFRU.IEDZ})`. I also created to parameter DateTime fields (from and to):

```
{@DateTime} >= {?Von} and 
{@DateTime} <= {?Bis}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 queries with 3 date filters and combine them and use as a `Add Command` in crystal reports